# Azure event hubs documentation seems to be conflicting with ms learning paths

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-eventhub

I'm currently in the process of studying for the Microsoft certification AZ 204. Which includes working with Event hubs and I'm confused about the following problem.

In the [learning docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/azure-event-hubs/2-event-hubs-overview) it is stated that: 'The number of partitions is specified at the time an Event Hubs is created and can't be changed.'

However when exercising using the Microsoft provided practice exam I got this question wrong: [image: practice exam question]

After looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventhubs/eventhub?view=azure-cli-latest#az-eventhubs-eventhub-update) for event hubs cli commands I see that it is possible to update the number of partitions with the following cli command 'az eventhubs eventhub update --partition-count'.

Is the learning doc outdated? Or am I missing something?

Comment: probably out dated. you may want to raise an issue on their github repo for documentation/learning path

Comment: Apparently you can report this on the learning page itself. I tried this first and I'll see what they respond. Thank you!

Comment: I can confirm that learn doc is in error.  Additional partitions can be added to an Event Hub, but only for the premium and dedicated tiers.  Thanks for reporting on the page, that will alert the content team and let them know to fix it.    More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/dynamically-add-partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft confirmed that the learn doc is in error. Additional partitions can be added to an Event Hub, but only for the premium and dedicated tiers. More information: [learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/dynamically-add-partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/dynamically-add-partitions)